Azure Function - Extensions do not meet the minimum requirements
Why am I getting this error on Azure function (runtime version 4)?
It works fine on my machine when using vscode. But doesn't work on azure function.
In my local machine I ran these two commands and then it started working.
dotnet add package Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB --version 3.0.9

dotnet add package Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage --version 4.0.4 

But I'm not sure how I can upgrade the version in Azure function or portal. I checked all settings and other json files and updated them to use the latest version. But I'm not sure why I'm still getting that error.
In the portal it shows the following error

Error building configuration in an external startup class.

and when I click that message I see the following output.

Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ExternalStartupException : Error building configuration in an external startup class.
---> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.HostInitializationException : One or more loaded extensions do not meet the minimum requirements. For more information see https://aka.ms/func-min-extension-versions.

ExtensionStartupType CosmosDBWebJobsStartup from assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB, Version=3.0.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' does not meet the required minimum version of 3.0.9.0. Update your NuGet package reference for Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB to 3.0.9 or later.
ExtensionStartupType AzureStorageWebJobsStartup from assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' does not meet the required minimum version of 4.0.4.0. Update your NuGet package reference for Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage to 4.0.4 or later.

 at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.DependencyInjection.ScriptStartupTypeLocator.ValidateExtensionRequirements(List`1 startupTypes)
 at /_/src/WebJobs.Script/DependencyInjection/ScriptStartupTypeLocator.cs : 335
 at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.DependencyInjection.ScriptStartupTypeLocator.GetExtensionsStartupTypesAsync()
 at /_/src/WebJobs.Script/DependencyInjection/ScriptStartupTypeLocator.cs : 22$1
 at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
 at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.DependencyInjection.ScriptStartupTypeLocator.<.ctor>b__10_0()
 at /_/src/WebJobs.Script/DependencyInjection/ScriptStartupTypeLocator.cs : 5$1
 at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
 at System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication,Boolean useDefaultConstructor)
 at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
 at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
 at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.DependencyInjection.ScriptStartupTypeLocator.GetStartupTypes()
 at /_/src/WebJobs.Script/DependencyInjection/ScriptStartupTypeLocator.cs : 6$1
 at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.WebJobsBuilderExtensions.UseExternalConfigurationStartup(IWebJobsConfigurationBuilder builder,IWebJobsStartupTypeLocator startupTypeLocator,WebJobsBuilderContext context,ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
 at D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Hosting\WebJobsBuilderExtensions.cs : 36$1
 at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ScriptHostBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass7_3.<AddScriptHostCore>b__8(IWebJobsStartupTypeLocator locator)
 at /_/src/WebJobs.Script/ScriptHostBuilderExtensions.cs : 263 End of inner exception


Any idea how to resolve the above error on Azure?


Nuke your bin and obj directories locally, and wipe-out the deployment filesystem then do msbuild YourSolution.sln /t:Restore followed by a clean rebuild and deploy.

@Robert Which version of Dotnet you are using? and isolated or in-process

As the error says package version is not supported.

Make sure you have added package in .cspoj file

<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage" Version="4.0.4" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB" Version="3.0.9" />


The versions you are using are very old version. Make sure you are using with .NET 6 in-porcess . webjobs packages support only in in-process model.

Below is given code which worked for me in .NET 6 in-porcess:

I am using Blob trigger with cosmosdb Output Binding to send data from blob file to cosmosdb.

*.csproj:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage" Version="4.0.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB" Version="3.0.9" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.4.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

BlobTrigger1.cs:
using System;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FuncApp
{
    public class BlobTrigger1
    {
        [FunctionName("BlobTrigger1")]
        public void Run([BlobTrigger("sample/{name}", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]Stream myBlob, string name,
        [CosmosDB(
                databaseName: "ToDoList",
                collectionName: "Items",
                ConnectionStringSetting = "CosmosDBConnection")]out dynamic document,
            ILogger log)
        {

            string blobContent;
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(myBlob))
            {
                blobContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }

            log.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{name} \n Size: {myBlob.Length} Bytes \n Content: {blobContent}");

            document = new
            {
                id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                BlobName = name,
                BlobLength = myBlob.Length,
                BlobContent = blobContent,
                CreatedAt = DateTime.UtcNow
            };
        }
    }
}

OUTPUT:


